# How to take a high-res screenshot with iphone (resolution is getting halved)

Tags: ios, iphone

I've downloaded an app on my phone and I'm trying to prepare some screenshots for the app store. Per documentation, the screenshots should be `1242 x 2208px` however when I take a screenshot and open it up on my desktop, I'm left with `674 x 1200px`. What can I do to get the proper resolution for these screenshots?

Comment: How are you taking the screenshot?  You should use the "take screenshot" button in the devices window in Xcode.

Comment: @Paulw11 I'm taking it with the device itself - home+power.  I don't have a mac unfortunately

Comment: You will need to get someone with a Mac to do it in Xcode for you

Comment: @Paulw11 there's no way to get full-res images from the device?